# Why redefining a variable does not always trigger an error?

Tags: go

I'm quite new to Go and I've stumble upon the following problem a few times already. I don't understand what's the underlying rule that allows (or not) the redefining of one variable with the help of `:=`.

Can you please explain to me why `test := func3()` does trigger an error in the first script but works fine in the second script?

The only thing that changes between both scripts is the position of the line that calls `func3()`.

Thanks!

## 1st script

https://play.golang.org/p/vvCI7nxHZL

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func func1() (string, string) {
  return "", ""
}

func func2() (string, string) {
  return "", ""
}

func func3() string {
  return ""
}

func main() {
  test, test2 := func1()
  test, test3 := func2()
  test := func3()

  fmt.Println(test, test2, test3)
}
```

## 2nd script

https://play.golang.org/p/BTTYCGEJ4E

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
)

func func1() (string, string) {
  return "", ""
}

func func2() (string, string) {
  return "", ""
}

func func3() string {
  return ""
}

func main() {
  test := func3()
  test, test2 := func1()
  test, test3 := func2()

  fmt.Println(test, test2, test3)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[As described in Effective Go](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#redeclaration), the `:=` operator, when the left part is a list of names, declares the ones which aren't already declared. An error is only raised when all are already declared.

This is especially convenient in this typical case:

```
a, err := someCall()
if (err) ...
b, err := someOtherCall()
if (err) ...
```

In the documentation terms:

> In a := declaration a variable v may appear even if it has already
>   been declared, provided:
>
> - this declaration is in the same scope as the existing declaration of v
>     (if v is already declared in an outer scope, the declaration will
>     create a new variable §),
> - the corresponding value in the
>     initialization is assignable to v, and
> - there is at least one other
>     variable in the declaration that is being declared anew.

Comment: Well, that was blazing fast! It finally make sense, Thanks!

Comment: I'll tack on you have to be extra careful with scoping when using loops inside functions and using :=. Take for example: https://play.golang.org/p/KGTcJ2xm00. It's the exact same loop both times, except the second defines err ahead of time so we don't have to use := in the loop to define err.